# Issues with comment voting in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, voting, android-app

I came across this interesting toast message when voting on comments in the Stack Exchange Android app:

[image]

- A "vote of comment"? Perhaps the message should be the same as on the site: `You may only submit a comment vote every X seconds`.
- Additionally, on the site I am rate-limited to five seconds, so the message is doubly wrong.
- Yet, the rate-limit doesn't seem to be strictly enforced. Sometimes I get this message, and at other times it lets me vote as many times as I like.
- <strike>There is no toast message, or any indication really, when you try to upvote a comment that you have already upvoted.</strike> Edit: this has been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. I'm going to go through it item by item:

1. The error message is dynamically generated based on what you're being throttled for and what action you're doing, so I don't think that's going to change anytime soon.
2. The API has different throttling limits than the website. [See here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle) for more information.
3. You may be facing this because the API considers upvoting, downvoting, undoing an upvote, and undoing a downvote all discrete actions that have their own rate-limits applied. That means that you can only upvote every N seconds but you can upvote immediately followed by undoing it without any lag.
4. That's a bug, it will be fixed.

Comment: 1: The dynamically inserted values can't be changed? 3: They were all comment upvotes. I was able to go through the comments on the Sandbox question and upvote several back-to-back before getting rate-limited.

Comment: They *can* be changed but I'm saying they're unlikely to change since at the moment one method call is controlling all of those error messages.

I'll take a look at comment voting in the morning and see if anything is off about it then, sorry for assuming it was question/answer voting.

Comment: It would be *so* much better if it just said "comment vote" instead of "vote of comment". Wouldn't that work for all the other actions you're swapping in that message, too? "Question vote", "Answer vote", "Delete vote", etc.