# Sharing a question from the Stack Exchange Android app doesn't use the shortened URL with my userid

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, sharing

When sharing the link for an question, the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is not the same as one would get when sharing from the site. It is the full URL, rather than the shortened one with the user id appended. (That is, on the app it's `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194872/issues-with-comment-voting-in-android-app` when the site gives `http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194872/168660`). Is this intentional?

Comment: I think this would more be a feature request than a bug report; As the software is Alpha, numerous features don't exist yet. I'm editing it accordingly for ya :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing a question now functions the same as sharing a question on the website. It'll go out in the next app update, thanks!