# "Open in browser" does nothing when Android app is set as default

Tags: bug, android-app

(This may be specific to the Galaxy, which is what I'm using)

When I click a link to an SE site in the Android app, it gives me an "open with" pop-up that has three options:

- Internet
- Chrome
- Stack Exchange

I can then choose to open SE posts like this "Just once" or "Always."

The problem is that when I set the SE app to "always," and I click "open in browser,"

- I choose Chrome in the pop-up
- The Chrome app opens the link
- I am then redirected back to the SE app (???)

This must be because it's trying to handle the "Always open in SE app" part. But the problem is that now the "Open in browser" option is pointless!

Could this be fixed somehow?

Comment: I see this on my end too, I can hotfix it by forcing the link to open up in Chrome rather than showing the pop-up dialog but that isn't a viable solution for everyone, I'll look into it thanks!

Comment: @HodofHod I'm doing something similar to that. When I use that directly it includes "Stack Exchange" in the list of items to choose from, which is odd. But even if I use that directly it still redirects back to the app on my device (Nexus 5 running 4.4) when I choose Chrome instead of Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Kasra, Right, I just realized. :D New solution: This issue is probably due to the fact that the app uses the shortened url (i.e.,  `q/216419/168660`) instead of the full one (`/questions/216419/open-in-browser-does-nothing-when-android-app-is-set-as-default`). Then, when Chrome gets a 301 redirect, it checks for a default app for the new URL, finds StackExchange, and opens it there. Maybe using the full link, thereby avoiding the 301, will solve the problem?

Comment: @HodofHod That is very likely the case. The switching of intent doesn't change until a page redirect in Chrome, so that would be triggering it. Sadly I don't know how to manually make that URL without doing bad hacks on the Android side.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi, Why can't you use the API? `/questions` returns a link item, with the full URL. (I assume you're already using the API for other things)

Comment: @HodofHod Because this would hopefully be using the "share" link found on the websites, which is the URL + a the person's account id.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi I thought that the id link was only necessary for the "Share" function. At least, that's all [I requested it for.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195128/168660) It used to use the full URL, so I know you can get that; is it not possible to use a different URL for "Share" and "Open in browser" functions? (Sorry if I'm being dense.)

Comment: @HodofHod Yeah it's possible to use the full URL for open in browser instead of the one with the tag for each... I'll look into seeing if that fixes this issue.

Comment: @Kasra, Have you been able to look into this at all? (I'm really sorry to be pushy :) )

Comment: @HodofHod I have looked into it. I'm still experimenting with different methods when creating the `Intent` to hope that I can do it without hacks.

Comment: I remember this bug, but is it still happening? I got [different behaviour (app crash!)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273486/open-in-browser-crashes-when-android-app-is-set-as-default?lq=1) on SE app v1.0.82 (beta)...

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi did you find a fix?